# Keyup ajax requests, aborting ajax requests for optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been trying to regulate the amount of ajax responses on `keyup` event, to optimize performance. Basically what I am trying to do is track whether there are any AJAX requests currently in progress and if there are, abort previous requests, so there is only one ajax request that ends up being completed at any given time. My current implementation does not seem to cancel previous ajax requests. I appreciate any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it.

Many thanks in advance!

```
var ajaxReq = null;

$(".invoice-wrapper").on("keyup", ".prod-name-input", $.throttle(800, function () {
    searchword = $(this).val();

    if ((searchword.length) >= 3) {
        if (ajaxReq != null) ajaxReq.abort();
        var ajaxReq = $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/data.php?searchword=" + searchword,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                $last.next('.suggestions').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}));
```

Comment: How does aborting the request regulate how many are being sent? if you have to abort it, it has already been sent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It doesn't. I'm trying to regulate the number of ajax responses rather. See edited.

Comment: Isn't that what you're throttle method is supposed to do? is it really taking longer than 800 ms to get results?

Comment: Yes. I suppose it doesn't do that successfully, because on long queries (3 words+) there are sometimes 4-5 ajax requests sent, none of which seem to be aborted using `ajaxReq.abort();`.

Comment: that's either some crazy slow typing, or the $.throttle isn't doing what it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Throttle seems to be working. `if (ajaxReq != null) ajaxReq.abort();` seems to not be doing what its supposed to.

Comment: ajaxReq should never be null after the first ajax request. additionally, my hunch is 9 times out of 10 it's trying to abort a request that has already completed. Using the throttle, it shouldn't be possible to send a request more frequently than once every 800ms if it's working correctly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37668/discussion-between-anchovylegend-and-kevin-b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're redefining the ajaxReq var inside the complete callback which makes the if statement always false, meaning you never abort any ajax requests. just remove the `var` from `ajaxReq` in the complete callback.

```
/*var */ajaxReq = $.ajax({
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var ajaxReq = null;
$(".invoice-wrapper").on("keyup",
    ".prod-name-input",
    $.throttle(800, function () {
  searchword = $(this).val();
  if ((searchword.length) >= 3) {
    if (ajaxReq === null) {
      ajaxReq = $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/data.php?searchword=" + searchword,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
          $last.next('.suggestions').html(data);
          ajaxReq = null;
        }
      });
    }
  }
}));
```

The idea to ONLY send the request when `ajaxReq` is `null`.

Comment: it does exactly opposite than what's required. It aborts next ajax calls if the current request is not completed

Answer (score 0):

your variable "ajaxReq" is a global variable, you should again assign "null" after the AJAX is success, Otherwise, the "ajaxReq" the object all alone.

```
success: function (data) {
    $last.next('.suggestions').html(data);
    ajaxReq = null;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
if ((searchword.length) >= 3) {
        if (ajaxReq != null) ajaxReq.abort();
        var ajaxReq = $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/data.php?searchword=" + searchword,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                 ajaxReq = null;
                $last.next('.suggestions').html(data);
            },
           error:function(){
                ajaxReq = null;
            }
        });
    }
```